# Spotify: Where excactly to put the app?

Tags: spotify

I have a Spotify developer account, this also shows in Spotify Client.
However, I'm having problems with my test app. I just copied the tutorial app from the Spotify deveopment pages.

In `Program files\Spotify` i put the folder `tutorial` with the app files.
I also made this directory: `Libraries\My Dokuments\Spotify\tutorial\`

This did not work. When searching for spotify:app:tutorial I got metadata error and "could not find this app". When changing the "t" to "T" (Tutorial with upper case T), I did not get "could not find"-message, but nothing happened. Also I got the message "metadatastarted" while "loading for ever".

I tried this path: `Users\P45\AppData\Local\Spotify\tutorial`

This did not help.

These are the directories I made:

- `Libraries\My Dokuments\Spotify\tutorial\`
- `Program files\Spotify\tutorial\`
- `Users\P45\AppData\Local\Spotify\tutorial\`

**Any suggestions?**

(Also, more info I should provide? Other changes?)

Answer (score 1):

Create "My Documents\Spotify" in your %USERPROFILE% folder (you should already have 'My Documents' there, assuming it is english windows, so just create "Spotify" under that), and then create your app folder, "tutorial" there. That is where your files should reside in.

Note that %USERPROFILE% probably does not point to 'Libraries' folder.

Metadata error however suggest you might have also an error with your application and not only with your folder path... if possible, post your manifest.json and index.html files, too, to fix that.

[This](https://github.com/eis/Spotify-Customscrobbler/tree/master/customscrobbler) is a simple app I made earlier on, you can check from there the bare minimum metadata stuff as well as the [instructions](https://github.com/eis/Spotify-Customscrobbler/wiki). For completeness, [this](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/) is the link to official instructions provided by Spotify.

Comment: Yes, it's My Dokuments from my default user (the one I'm using).
I'm using the latest stable Spotify version on W7 (obviously :P)

I will check my app files, maybe that's why it don't work.

I wil try to just copy your and se if that changes anything.

Comment: so it's really `My Dokuments` and not `My Documents`? Because it might be that Spotify doesn't take into account the localized versions... never know, you maybe ought to try with creating `My Documents` for this purpose and see if it would work.

Comment: Sorry, here it actually is "Dokumenter", since I have the Norwegian version of Windows (yeah, it's horrible, I want English!). But the directory is correct. :)

I will try your files soon I hope, I'm a bit busy now. :O